# How can I get sql to return @cardType variable data into my table

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, stored-procedures

## Directions

Write a proceedure called GetAllCustomerLevelsthat returns the customerNumber, customerName, and cardtype for all customers.
Hint: Use CASE in your select statement. See: Case in Select Statement at stackoverflow or MySQL CASE operator from w3resource. This could also be done using a nested IF. See: Inline IF and CASE statements in MySQL from timmurphy.
Below is an example proceedure that returns the customerNumber and customerName for all customers:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllCustomerLevels;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllCustomerLevels()
 
BEGIN

    select customerNumber, customerName
    from customers;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

3. Save the sql that created the GetAllCustomerLevels procedure as GetAllCustomerLevels.sql

#### One of my Attempts

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllCustomerLevels2;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllCustomerLevels2()
 
BEGIN
    DECLARE creditlimit double;
    call GetCustomerLevel(@customerNumber,@cardType);
    select customerNumber, customerName, @cardType
    from customers
    end; 
    
    SET @cardType =
        (CASE 
            WHEN (creditlimit > 50000) THEN 'PLATINUM'
            WHEN (creditlimit <= 50000 AND creditlimit >= 10000) THEN 'GOLD'
            WHEN (creditlimit < 10000) THEN 'SILVER'
            ELSE 'No card'
            END 
            );
  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My result returns customerName and customerNumber but @cardType stays empty.

Comment: You need to put your case when in to your select, i.e. select customerNumber, customerName, (CASE 
            WHEN (creditlimit > 50000) THEN 'PLATINUM' .....
    from customers